# How to exclude tags with patterns in gitlab ci config

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a gitlab repo and I am trying to create some tags on top of required commits. But my CICD library (included) is having a job (`job1`) in a stage which runs on every tag/branch/commit. I want to exclude it to run on particular formats of tags. (eg. `pre_final-2.3.1`).

I tried giving the tag pattern in my `.gitlab-ci.yaml` in the except section of the job as below.

Eg:

```
job1:
  except:
    - ^pre_final-\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
```

It is still adding the job `job1` to the pipeline for the CICD builds running on this tag. I believe this pattern is checking with branch name. But is there a way to mention the `ref` we provide in the except section is branch or tag?

Ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefs--exceptrefs

Answer (score 0):

You should [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) instead as `only`/`except` is not developed further. There you can check for the the name of your tag.

```
job1:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^pre_final-\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate classification as branch or tag while using them in only/except.
I realized that I am giving a wrong regex pattern and thus it is not working for the tag pattern I am trying for

`^pre_final-\d+\.\d+\.\d+$` --> `/^pre_final-\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/`

So my .gitlab-ci.yaml contains as below

```
job1:
  except:
    # matches with branch or tags names
    - /^pre_final-\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
```

Since above usage matches both branch and tag names, if we want to match only branch name or match only tag name, then we can use the below format

```
job1:
  except:
    variables:
      # to match only tag names
      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG == /^pre_final-\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
      # to match only branch names
      - $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH = /^pre_final-\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
```